# Which dependencies to use between Firebase and Google Play Services?

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-services

I recently started playing with Firebase, but I cannot completely understand its relation with Google Play Services. I know that Firebase is a mobile platform, and on Android it is based on Google Play Services, but why there are some modules with the same name of the ones of Google Play Services?

For example, in my `build.gradle` I can have:

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.4.0
com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.4.0
```

but also:

```
com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.4.0
com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.4.0
```

I see that on [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) there is the list of available components (and note that the last one is actually a Google Play Services module):

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.4.0
```

The [same list for Google Play Services](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup) is much longer, so some modules are not available using only Firebase dependencies. Which dependencies should I use and why? Can I use mixed dependencies?

Comment: You can use either of them . Firebase is primarily for analytics. firebase-ads does nothing but just refer to play-services-ads. Google recommends use of firebase so as to keep all libraries under one big umbrella.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On this new Firebase (from May 18th), Google added a few existing services to it. Google Play Services already had features like: Analytics, AdMob, Test Lab, etc. And you could use them from your Google Developer Console.

But then, they decided to merge some of those features with firebase. This way, you can have all of the features "together" on your Firebase Console. They are now unified to give your users a better experience and to help you (as a developer) easily manage your project.

So, if you want to use firebase, you should use the firebase dependencies. The Google play dependencies are meant for projects created on the Google Developer Console.

Comment: I don't think so: in the [official guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin) they add both of them. In my understanding, Google Play Services is just another provider (like Facebook or Twitter) for Firebase, but I'm not sure if this is true for all of Firebase modules.

Comment: @manfcas , Auth is a bit different from the other services. They add both because the firebase one is supposed to guarantee firebase Auth, and the play services auth is supposed to guarantee sign in with Google. If you check the guide for other services, you'll notice they don't add both.