# Which is the current Android standard, Firebase or Play Services?

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-services

I am building an Android application which uses services such as authentication. 
I am deciding between using Firebase and Play Services.
I simply want to use what is the best practice.
I am not trying to find opinion or discussion, I want to do what is right for Android, what is the de facto standard, what is the proper 'native' way of doing it.
I do not really mind about issues with functionality as I want to use what is 'proper'.
However, I could not find any definitive instructions or sites about whether to use Firebase or Play Services.
Which should I use?

This question has been discussed last year on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38688264/which-dependencies-to-use-between-firebase-and-google-play-services) and [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/4k8pl4/firebase_and_google_play_services_have_a_lot_of/?st=j70f8kbd&sh=d9bc8ed0). 
Personally I think that the answer is use Firebase whenever possible, and use Play Services for the rest. I think Play Services and Firebase share some functionality in common but Google is transitioning those functionality into Firebase.

Last year, both services were more identical, however Google has been actively updating Firebase, so although it hasn't been directly announced, it looks like the relevant Play Services functionality is unofficially deprecated in favor of Firebase.

Or perhaps mixed, as this image when setting up Google's Play Games Services would suggest.
[image]

Which is the proper standard?

Comment: "uses services such as authentication" it's too vague. You have to be more specific than that.

Comment: I&#39;m making an Android game that uses authentication and syncs data with a web application which also uses authentication. A game with highscores. I looked at Play Services API which doesn't even mention Firebase, yet Firebase docs is all about migrating from Play Services.

Comment: *although it hasn't been directly announced, it looks like the relevant Play Services functionality is unofficially deprecated in favor of Firebase* there is no such thing as unofficial deprecation. It is either deprecated or it is not

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: I am building an Android game and want to use authentication and leaderboards. I want this information to stay in sync with a Javascript website. I looked at Google Play Services, Play Games Services and Firebase but can't figure out which one I am supposed to use. Google keeps hinting that I am supposed to use Firebase but does not say it directly or officially. I tried reading the documentation but there is no official instruction. Which service is appropriate to use? It [looks](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/integrate-play-games) like  mix and match while preferring Firebase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the simple answer is **Firebase**.

It won't be false to say that Google is firing all cylinders to shift the dev works to Firebase.

As mentioned in a [blogpost](http://blog.safedk.com/technology/mobile-sdks-firebase-or-play-services/)

> Firebase is this big SDK from the house of the rising Google that
>   answers many of a developer’s needs with the premise being “and it’s
>   all completely free”.
>
> Analytics, Crash Reporting, Database, Storage space, Push
>   Notifications and more.
>
> Some aren’t even mobile SDKs, just great services for developers such
>   as hosting services and so on. The key is solving all of this
>   confusion is to understand this is as simple as a game of marketing.
>   Google introduced brilliant new capabilities with Firebase.

**New in Firebase from I/O 2017:**

1. Fabric
2. Phone Authentication
3. Performance Monitoring
4. Cloud Functions
5. Better Analytics

Read more at the official blogs to get a better understanding - [link](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/05/whats-new-from-firebase-at-google-io.html)

Comment: The answer content is from http://blog.safedk.com/technology/mobile-sdks-firebase-or-play-services/ I actually read it before posting the question. However, I was surprised by the absence of direct official statements from Google or Android documentation about this.

Comment: The layering is currently been done so that Play Services can be used with the Firebase. But with the response, Firebase has received by the community, the platform will completely migrate to Firebase. So it's better to start off with it

Comment: please provide attribution when copying text from blog posts etc